# Problems using zsh with Catalina, Python/Python3, pip/pip3, PATH, zshrc, etc

Tags: python, path, zsh, zshrc, macos-catalina

I recently updated to Catalina and the default zsh. I probably messed up paths during the transition, and I'm currently trying to sort out the locations of Python3.7, pip3, the command-line PATH and my zshrc file.

It looks as if there are potentially redundant files contained within /usr/bin, /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/Cellar/python and /Users/[user]/.local/bin

The following are reproductions of commands:

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

```
$ which pip
pip not found
```

```
$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

```
$ pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pip3", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

```
$ cat ~/.zshrc
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/[user]/.local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/[user]/anaconda3/bin:/Users/[user]/anaconda3/bin:/Users/[user]/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/[user]/anaconda3:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot all of this? From what I understand: I only need Python2.x for OS; with Catalina I should now be storing Python3.x **only** within my User (not in /usr)? pip3 is automatically installed with Python3.x (although mine is returning an error) and also should be installed within my User and not in /usr? Also, my $PATH still contains remnants, e.g., Anaconda, which I have since removed... how/where do I update my $PATH? Within the zshrc file?

Comment: It seems that regardless of edits (e.g., I removed anaconda from my /etc/paths file because I am no longer using it), which python and which python3 point to /usr/bin instead of another location.

Comment: `which -a` will show you *all* possible paths that match, in the order they appear in `PATH`. That information may prove useful.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue after updating `pip` using `sudo pip3 install ---upgrade pip` on Catalina. However, using `python3 -m pip` sitll works. You could use this as a workaround.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've experienced this issue after a clean installation of Catalina. I'm also using `zsh`.

**What I did wrong:**

I've installed a new version of `pip` by using:

```sh
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

as prompted. However, this will not work with Apple's `python`, as the path will not be correct. Instead, `sudo -H` should be used.

**How I fixed pip:**

Fortunately, `python3 -m pip` still works as a workaround for `pip3`.

Install an older version of `pip` (in my case, `19.3.0` was sufficient):

```
sudo -H python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip==19.3.0
```

and then upgrade again:

```
sudo -H python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I hope this will also solve your issue.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem with mkdocs, but a version of it did. In case it helps anyone else, mkdocs appears to require pip vs pip3

`sudo -H python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip==19.3.0`

`which pip`

`pip install mkdocs`

`mkdocs`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as you. Solved with

```
brew install python3
```

Comment: Exact same setup and error as OP, not solved by this.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. You can use

```
rehash
```

in your command line to update your paths. It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by deleting ~/Library/Python.

Comment: Please whenever you answer a question or add any comment, make sure that it is in such a format which is understandable by other people and makes sense, if a new user comes in.

Answer (score 1):

I was also running in to this issue on a fresh install of MacOS Catalina with Kitty term `emulator + ohmyzsh`.

Reading this question led me to my `.zshrc` which still had the line commented

```
\#export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I removed the comment, which added the $HOME/bin to the PATH

```
~/.zshrc

export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This change allowed me to successfully run the `pip3` command without the traceback error.

Answer (score 1):

The solution didn't work for me. After reinstalling python3 with this command:
`brew reinstall python3` I did this:

`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install`

I read it from this website:
https://mikebeach.org/2020/02/08/pip3-crashes-on-macos-catalina/

I hope it helps you guys